# VBA ERROR 91 Object Variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba

Появляется одна и та же ошибка даже когда я делаю set. Я думаю и без перевода этих иероглифов внутри кавычек понятно что происходит. VBA изучаю 3-й день так что не ругайтесь пожалуйста

```
Sub Button2()
Dim col As Object, cell As Object, current As Object, ratingcell As Object
Dim firstcell As String

For Each col In Sheets("Ïîñòàâêè").Range("A1 : " & Sheets("Ïîñòàâêè").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address)
    If col.Value <> "Äàòà" And InStr(col.Value, "+") = False Then
        For Each cell In Sheets("Ïîñòàâêè").Range(Sheets("Ïîñòàâêè").Range(col.Address).Offset(2, -1).Address & " : " & Sheets("Ïîñòàâêè").Range(col.Address).Offset(2, -1).End(xlDown).Address)
            If Not Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1 : " & Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Find(What:=cell.Value) Is Nothing Then
                Set current = Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1 : " & Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Find(What:=cell.Value)
                Set ratingcell = Sheets("Ðåéòèíã ÿ÷ååê").Range("A1").End(xlDown)
                firstcell = current.Address
                Do
//ошибку выдает в следующей строчке
                    If Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1 : " & Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Find(What:=Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range(current.Address).Offset(0, 5).Value).Row < Sheets("Ðåéòèíã ÿ÷ååê").Range(ratingcell.Address).Row Then 
                        Set ratingcell = Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1 : " & Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Find(What:=Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range(current.Address).Offset(0, 5).Value)
                    End If
                    Set current = Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1 : " & Sheets("Íîâûå Îñòàòêè").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).FindNext(current)
                Loop While current.Address <> firstcell And Not current Is Nothing
                MsgBox ratingcell.Address
            End If
        Next cell
        col.Value = col.Value & " +"
        Exit For
    End If
Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: Разбейте комплексную строку кода на отдельные "шаги", используйте промежуточные переменные соотв. типов.

Comment: Чтобы не было кракзябликов, копировать код нужно НЕ при английской раскладке. По вопросу: проще разобраться, если бы вопрос был поставлен по задаче ("хочу это и то, не получается"). Много текста в коде, изучайте оператор *With/End With*